# Is Tor-network protected from using one hop?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, relays

I'm testing few things in Tor and I noticed that if im changing(from the source code) the number of hop's(nodes) to be more then 3 hop's it work fine(slow but still working) and if i set only 2 hop's its still works great.
but, when im setting only 1 hop i can open the Tor-browser but i can't use it to visit site(regular site and onion site too).
so i'm thinking maybe the Tor-network is protected from using one hop?